# Moving a document library item from one folder to another including version history using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, document

Using Sharepoint 2007 object model, I have been looking for an example in C# to move an item from one document library to another on the same server and saving the version history (i.e. SPListItemVersion objects) and metadata (the folders have the same content types, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do with the following code:

```
    /// <summary>  
    /// Adds item to archive  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="item">Item to add</param>  
    /// <param name="destination">Archive path</param>  
    /// <param name="destination">web site of archive</param>  
    /// <returns>Result of arhivation process</returns>  
    public static string ArchiveItem(SPListItem item, string destination, SPWeb web)
    {
        // Save main meta information for later use:  
        var author = item.File.Author;
        var modifiedBy = item.File.ModifiedBy;
        var modified = item.File.TimeLastModified;

        var created = item.File.TimeCreated;
        // Get destination filename:  
        var destinationFile = destination + "/" + item.File.Name;
        // Copy the item and set properties:  
        var coppiedFile = web.GetFolder(destination).Files.Add(
            destinationFile,
            item.File.OpenBinary(),
            author,
            modifiedBy,
            created,
            modified
        );
        coppiedFile.Item["Created"] = created;
        coppiedFile.Item["Modified"] = modified;
        // Save changes, UpdateOverwriteVersion causes object to save without saving a new version.
        coppiedFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        // If moving is enabled, delete original item:  
        item.Delete();

        return coppiedFile.ServerRelativeUrl;
    }
```